# Why is my SPD 2010 workflow running twice?

Tags: 2010, list, sharepoint-designer, workflow, powershell

I've got a support case for a client, and they have a super simple workflow on a list.  It simply sends an email to a user from a person field, whenever an item is added to the list.  The client reported duplicate e-mails being sent out from the workflow.  After examining the workflow history, I found that the workflow was being triggered twice every time an item was added to a list.  So I decided to dig into the list's Schema.XML, and found the following:

```
<Receiver><Name/><Synchronization>2</Synchronization><Type>10001</Type><SequenceNumber>1</SequenceNumber><Assembly>Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c</Assembly><Class>Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowAutostartEventReceiver</Class><Data/></Receiver>
<Receiver><Name/><Synchronization>2</Synchronization><Type>10001</Type><SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber><Assembly>Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c</Assembly><Class>Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowAutostartEventReceiver</Class><Data/></Receiver>
<Receiver><Name/><Synchronization>2</Synchronization><Type>10002</Type><SequenceNumber>1</SequenceNumber><Assembly>Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c</Assembly><Class>Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowAutostartEventReceiver</Class><Data/></Receiver>
<Receiver><Name/><Synchronization>2</Synchronization><Type>10002</Type><SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber><Assembly>Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c</Assembly><Class>Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowAutostartEventReceiver</Class><Data/></Receiver>
```

Then I examined a list where I knew the workflow was only firing once per list item added, and found the following:

```
<Receiver><Name/><Synchronization>2</Synchronization><Type>10001</Type><SequenceNumber>1</SequenceNumber><Assembly>Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c</Assembly><Class>Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowAutostartEventReceiver</Class><Data/></Receiver>
<Receiver><Name/><Synchronization>2</Synchronization><Type>10002</Type><SequenceNumber>1</SequenceNumber><Assembly>Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c</Assembly><Class>Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowAutostartEventReceiver</Class><Data/></Receiver>
```

The client reported that at some point, the site containing the list experiencing the issue had a backup performed on it, then it accidentally was restored to the same location.

I suspect the doubling of the SPWorkflowAutoStartEventReceiver is causing the workflow to trigger twice on this?  Are my suspicions correct?  And could restoring a site to the same location it was backed up from cause this?

Also, this is what I came across to fix this issue...has anyone actually used this method?
[SPD Workflow Doubling Solution](http://sharelockpoint.wordpress.com/2011/09/26/sharepoint-designer-workflow-fired-twice-in-a-migrated-list/)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the duplicate registrations are what is causing the problem. You can use a tool like [SPManager](https://spmanager.codeplex.com/) to remove the duplicate instances.